# Infinite list parallel filter in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, infinite

I want to find the first matching element in a infinite list in Haskell.

This code is working:

```
findPassword passwordHash = (head . filter (checkPassword passwordHash)) allStrings
```

checkPassword is really long (because it's a SHA1 hash)

```
checkPassword hash string = (sha1 string) == hash
```

allStrings is just the list of all possible strings:

```
allStrings = [ c : s | s <- "" : allStrings, c <- ['a'..'z'] ++ ['0'..'9'] ]
```

I want this code to be run in parallel but if I replace filter by parFilter:

```
import qualified Control.Parallel.Strategies as S
parFilter p = S.withStrategy (S.evalBuffer 1000 S.rseq) . filter p
```

It doesn't work… Do you have an idea? This code is also using a lot of memory but it's another problem.
The full script is available here https://github.com/ThibaudDauce/habreaker

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: it just run forever and eat all my RAM and all my processor

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure you want to use `parBuffer` instead of `evalBuffer`.

See this SO answer for a good explanation:

[How to choose between parList and parBuffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5352683/866915)

Here is some demo code:

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import System.Environment
import Debug.Trace

fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-2) + fib (n-1)

fib' n | trace "calling fib" False = undefined
fib' n = fib n

theList = cycle [30,31,32]

firstN :: Int -> [Int]
firstN n = take n $ filter even $ map fib' theList

firstNpar :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
firstNpar n k = take n $ filter even $ runEval $ parBuffer k rseq $ map fib' theList

main = do
  (argn : argk : _) <- getArgs
  let n = read argn
  case argk of
    "" -> print $ firstN n
    _  -> let k = read argk in
          print $ firstNpar n k
```

Example runs:

```
prog 20 2 +RTS -N2         -- I only have two cores
prog 20 ''                 -- run single threaded
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working (https://github.com/ThibaudDauce/habreaker) but it's not faster… :-( And I don't see all my processors working…

Comment: Try using `rdeepseq` instead of `rseq`. `rseq` works for my example because the result of `fib` is just number, but you are computing a pair so evaluating to WHNF won't compute the hash.